# Kibana health prob fails when elasticsearch host is added to fluentd-forwarder-cm

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana, fluentd

I am trying to setup EFK stack in a aws cluster using `helm`.

These are the steps I followed.

1. Created a separate namespace `logging`
2. Installed elastic search

```
 helm install elasticsearch elastic/elasticsearch -f values.yml -n logging
```

values.yml

```
 # Shrink default JVM heap.
 esJavaOpts: "-Xmx128m -Xms128m"

 # Allocate smaller chunks of memory per pod.
 resources:
   requests:
     cpu: "100m"
     memory: "512M"
   limits:
     cpu: "1000m"
     memory: "512M"

 # Request smaller persistent volumes.
 volumeClaimTemplate:
   accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
   storageClassName: default
   resources:
     requests:
       storage: 1Gi
```

3. Installed kibana

```
 helm install kibana elastic/kibana -n logging
```

4. Installed fluentdb

```
 helm install fluentd bitnami/fluentd -n logging
```

5. Created ingress for kibana

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service-api
  namespace: logging
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-example-prod"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - logs.example.in
    secretName: mySecret
  rules:
  - host: logs.example.in
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: kibana-kibana
            port:
              number:  5601
```

At this point everything works.

I can go to `logs.example.in` to view the kibana dashboard.
I can also exec into any pod and run,

```
curl elasticsearch-master.logging.svc.cluster.local
```

...and it gives response.

---

When I update `fluent-forwarder-cm` ConfigMap and provide elasticsearch host like below

```
{
    "fluentd-inputs.conf": "# HTTP input for the liveness and readiness probes
        <source>
          @type http
          port 9880
        </source>
        # Get the logs from the containers running in the node
        <source>
          @type tail
          path /var/log/containers/*.log
          # exclude Fluentd logs
          exclude_path /var/log/containers/*fluentd*.log
          pos_file /opt/bitnami/fluentd/logs/buffers/fluentd-docker.pos
          tag kubernetes.*
          read_from_head true
          <parse>
            @type json
          </parse>
        </source>
        # enrich with kubernetes metadata
        <filter kubernetes.**>
          @type kubernetes_metadata
        </filter>
        ",
    "fluentd-output.conf": "# Throw the healthcheck to the standard output instead of forwarding it
        <match fluentd.healthcheck>
          @type stdout
        </match>
        
        # Forward all logs to the aggregators
        <match **>
          @type elasticsearch
          include_tag_key true
          host \"elasticsearch-master.logging.svc.cluster.local\"
          port \"9200\"
          logstash_format true
          <buffer>
            @type file
            path /opt/bitnami/fluentd/logs/buffers/logs.buffer
            flush_thread_count 2
            flush_interval 5s
          </buffer>
        </match>
        ",
    "fluentd.conf": "# Ignore fluentd own events
        <match fluent.**>
          @type null
        </match>
        
        @include fluentd-inputs.conf
        @include fluentd-output.conf
        ",
    "metrics.conf": "# Prometheus Exporter Plugin
        # input plugin that exports metrics
        <source>
          @type prometheus
          port 24231
        </source>
        # input plugin that collects metrics from MonitorAgent
        <source>
          @type prometheus_monitor
          <labels>
            host #{hostname}
          </labels>
        </source>
        # input plugin that collects metrics for output plugin
        <source>
          @type prometheus_output_monitor
          <labels>
            host #{hostname}
          </labels>
        </source>
        # input plugin that collects metrics for in_tail plugin
        <source>
          @type prometheus_tail_monitor
          <labels>
            host #{hostname}
          </labels>
        </source>
        "
}
```

I get errors.

1st Error,

```
 kubectl describe pod kibana-kibana-7f47d4b8c5-7r8x7 -n logging

Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                   From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  24m                   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned logging/kibana-kibana-7f47d4b8c5-7r8x7 to ip-172-20-32-143.ap-south-1.compute.internal
  Normal   Pulled     24m                   kubelet            Container image "docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.12.0" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    24m                   kubelet            Created container kibana
  Normal   Started    24m                   kubelet            Started container kibana
  Warning  Unhealthy  22m                   kubelet            Readiness probe failed: Error: Got HTTP code 000 but expected a 200
  Warning  Unhealthy  4m28s (x25 over 24m)  kubelet            Readiness probe failed: Error: Got HTTP code 503 but expected a 200
```

2nd Error,

```
GET https://logs.example.in/ 
503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
```

3rd Error,
Doing

```
curl elasticsearch-master.logging.svc.cluster.local:9200
```

from inside any pod give `timedout error`

Comment: Then forget about kibana and fluentd for now, focus on elasticsearch: why isn't that service responding? Are those pods up and running? Have you set `sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144` on your k8s nodes? Are you sure those memory limits/jvm params and PVC size aren't too low? Check pod descriptions, events in namespace and container logs

Comment: It only happens when `fluentd-forwarder-cm` is updated with `elasticsearch` host.

Comment: Right, then elasticsearch can't take the load and somehow gets unavailable. forkget about kibana/fuentd ...Check pod description, events in namespace and container logs. Edit your post pasting those. Try with a larger PVC: when ES data disk reaches 80% occupation, it would put itself in read-only. Could be related to memory - again, those xmx/xms/limits/requests look too low: kubernetes is going to generate lots of logs.